# PHP can't read my html inside a file

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I have a template class that I can echo out files through it.
I give the address of my file to template class and echo it out.
I have 4 files named: index, topic, topics, register and all of them are doing perfect but topic.php is empty.here is my code for example for the register inside a register controller file.what should I do? thank you.

```
<?php 
$template = new template('templates/register.php');//include the template
//display template
echo $template;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php 
    $template = file_get_contents('templates/register.php'); //include the template
    //display template
    echo $template;
```

If you want to use the code for some other purpose like for including its content you should instead use `include('file_url');`

Refer https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: It worked but It brings only the HTML.my problem is : it works for all of other files but for topic.php I don't know why ???

Comment: What you expected

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to echo an object and not a string.

Does it work with this template function?

```
/**
 * Render template
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param array $data
 * @return mixed
 */
function render($fileName, $data = array())
{
    ob_start();
    extract($data);
    require $fileName;
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
}
```

Usage

```
$template = render('templates/register.php');
echo $template;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough contributions that is why am posting as answer.
Have you tried

```
include('templates/register.php');
```

You want your HTML to be inserted in every page. I think this might work

Answer (score 0):

I found why this is happening.this is because in classes folder, I have a template class and a topic class and topic is empty.
PHP goes to this directory(I don't know why !!!!).. and echo out topic class except topic file.